# How to put values in a Function automatically

Tags: r, function, for-loop, model, subset

I have a data.frame

```
                                      Team    Ability        SE
 Amur Khabarovsk           Amur Khabarovsk   0.0000000 0.0000000
 Sibir Novosibirsk       Sibir Novosibirsk  -0.2523662 0.7325424
 Lokomotiv Yaroslavl   Lokomotiv Yaroslavl   1.8614021 0.7883580
 HC Red Star Kunlun     HC Red Star Kunlun  -1.2255611 0.9341483
 HC Sochi                         HC Sochi  -0.2862795 0.7735475
 SKA St. Petersburg     SKA St. Petersburg   0.9110674 0.6958989
```

and I have this function

```
BT <- function(deltaa,deltab){
  exp(deltaa-deltab) / (1 + exp(deltaa-deltab))
```

deltaa,deltab will be values from ability column in data.frame i.e

```
    > BT(    1.8614021,1.6718526    )
    [1] 0.547246


 How do I put these values in BT(function), based on team column of data.frame?
```

I've got it to this, but how do I change the team names in the filters without manually doing it?

```
BT(  home_team$Ability,away_team$Ability    )
        home_team <- filter(KHL_Abilities,Team==" Jokerit ")
        away_team <- filter(KHL_Abilities, Team==" HC Sochi ")
> BT(    home_team$Ability,away_team$Ability    )
[1] 0.8763307
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. You can store the results for your function `BT` in a new variable and call as first argument of it to the variable `Ability`. Here the code:

```
#Function
BT <- function(deltaa,deltab){
  exp(deltaa-deltab) / (1 + exp(deltaa-deltab))}
#Create var
df$Result <- BT(deltaa = df$Ability,deltab = 1.6718526)
```

Output:

```
                 Team    Ability        SE     Result
1     Amur Khabarovsk  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.15817734
2   Sibir Novosibirsk -0.2523662 0.7325424 0.12739185
3 Lokomotiv Yaroslavl  1.8614021 0.7883580 0.54724600
4  HC Red Star Kunlun -1.2255611 0.9341483 0.05228156
5            HC Sochi -0.2862795 0.7735475 0.12366934
6  SKA St. Petersburg  0.9110674 0.6958989 0.31847582
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Team = c("Amur Khabarovsk", "Sibir Novosibirsk", 
"Lokomotiv Yaroslavl", "HC Red Star Kunlun", "HC Sochi", "SKA St. Petersburg"
), Ability = c(0, -0.2523662, 1.8614021, -1.2255611, -0.2862795, 
0.9110674), SE = c(0, 0.7325424, 0.788358, 0.9341483, 0.7735475, 
0.6958989)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In order to avoid filter and other dataframes try this:

```
#Code
BT(df$Ability[df$Team=='Amur Khabarovsk'],df$Ability[df$Team=='HC Red Star Kunlun'])
```

Output (using shared data):

```
[1] 0.7730407
```

**Update:** I have made some changes to `BT` so that you can use it with home/away team:

```
#Function 2
BT <- function(data,home,away){
  home <- subset(data,Team==home)
  away <- subset(data,Team==away)
  #Obtain values
  deltaa <- home$Ability
  deltab <- away$Ability
  exp(deltaa-deltab) / (1 + exp(deltaa-deltab))}
#Apply
BT(df,home = 'Amur Khabarovsk',away = 'HC Red Star Kunlun')
```

Comment: Ok got it to this 'BT(  home_team$Ability,away_team$Ability )
home_team <- filter(KHL_Abilities,Team==" Jokerit ")
away_team <- filter(KHL_Abilities, Team==" HC Sochi ")' But I want the team names in the filters to be able to change with out me manually doing it

Comment: @Drew I have added an update, also try with this (no need of creating more dataframes): `BT(df$Ability[df$Team=='Amur Khabarovsk'],df$Ability[df$Team=='HC Red Star Kunlun'])` you can set the teams as you wish. I hope that helps you!

Comment: Yes but what I am trying to do is change the teams, based on who is playing a game, without doing it manually?

Comment: @Drew Do you have another dataframe? How do you define who is playing, maybe a vector of values?

Comment: @Drew I have added an update with changes to `BT`. I hope that can help you!